# Why does text-align not work first-line pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

I want to align some paragraph and the first-line should be aligned to the left, but the second line to the right. If I set it this way with the pseudo element it doesnt work.

Example:

```
.title{
  text-align: right;
}
.title:first-line{
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

The first line is bold, but it is not aligned to the left.
Is there a way for this to work? I'm testing it on Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line is rendered like an inline pseudo-element; as such, the `text-align` property cannot be applied to it.

Due to its nature, there is no way you can change the alignment of the first line of text; it always follows the text alignment of its parent block container. You cannot even change how it is displayed, for example, you can't hide it with `display: none`, or turn it into an inline-block with `display: inline-block` in an attempt to apply the `text-align` property.

Furthermore, the spec lists [certain restrictions to `::first-line`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-formatted-line), such as only certain properties being applicable:

> The `::first-line` pseudo-element is similar to an inline-level element, but with certain restrictions. The following CSS properties apply to a `::first-line` pseudo-element: font properties, color property, background properties, ‘word-spacing’, ‘letter-spacing’, ‘text-decoration’, ‘vertical-align’, ‘text-transform’, ‘line-height’. UAs may apply other properties as well.

If you need the first line to be aligned differently, you'll have to wrap the contents of the first line in another element such as `<span>`, then make that `<span>` an inline-block with a width of 100%. Only then can you apply `text-align: left` and it will work. The difficult part is, of course, determining what exactly constitutes the first line, unless you have a fixed breakpoint using something like a `<br>` in which case just wrap everything before the first `<br>` in a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

The following properties can be used with :first-line :

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- word-spacing
- letter-spacing
- text-decoration
- vertical-align
- text-transform
- line-height
- clear

Answer (score 0):

```
The ::first-line selector is used to add a style to the first line of the specified selector.

 The following properties can be used with ::first-line: 

    font properties
    color properties 
    background properties
    word-spacing
    letter-spacing
    text-decoration
    vertical-align
    text-transform
    line-height
    clear

The ::first-line selector can only be used with block-level elements.
```

Comment: i'd suggest avoiding links and reference to w3schools since it contains heavily outdated information...

Comment: I don't think he means removing the reference link by itself. He means quoting a different source entirely. Also, quotes are not marked up like code - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for help on quoting other sources.